# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I didn't find out what's causing the problem below. Could you help me, please?

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.2
>   Install Repository and sync project
> Open File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: Could you show your app's `build.gradle`?

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, then can you accept it, so it could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 50):

You have to update Application level build.gradle to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` from 2.x.x. Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you so much! been trying to solve this for hours

Comment: This will require you require you to generate a new `google-service.json` for your app if upgrading from 8.x.x or earlier.  Head to https://console.firebase.google.com/ and to your project settings to generate an updated version.

Answer (score 12):

Update your android sdk manager -  Google repository version to 28 & Google play services to 30. It will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone has this problem and have updated SDK and still isnt working my fix was the google play services version in my build code read 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'
and I changed it to
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the last '0' solved the problem. Must be com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0

Comment: @Andrew My sdk is up to date (Google Repository Rev 32 & Google Play Services Rev 32) in Application level build.gradle I have "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'" Still I am getting error: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by uninstall Google Repository from SDK Manager then install it again. Hope this helps