# failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.82

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, version

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.82'

}
```

i have click on 
install repository and sync project

but does not work, Why?.
And i am new to location based services and having problem with coding. i am using genymotion google-play-service version(9.0.82) so that it will be compatible to run in that virtual device(api 14: 4.1.1 ).

> And does it matter SDK manager's google-play-service version ?(i have already latest update on google play services rev 29 on SDK)
>   please help me i got stuck.

Comment: i still get confused, which google-play-service version should i use either of SDK manager or Genymotion virtual device ?

Comment: Check this SO question [Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712226/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement9-0-2?rq=1) and [Upgrade to Google Play Services:9.0.0 Error Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi?rq=1) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install Google services on your Genymotion device?
If Google Play Services on Android 6.0 crash everytime, you can try do  the same things in this sequence. Maybe it will work.

Here is what I did:

1. Install a latest Genymotion (version 2.6.0 in my case). Make sure
   the previous old (preview) Android 6.0 images are removed(Genymotion
   -> Settings -> Misc -> Clear cache).
2. Add a new virtualdevice, select Google Nexus 5X and Android 6.0
   image. It should download a new image from Genymotion website.Start
   created Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 virtual device.
3. Flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip (drag&drop the zip file to
   virtual device window) and then restart the virtual device.
4. Flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip and restart the virtual device again. Now
   add Google account in the virtual device via Settings -> Accounts ->
   Add account. Do not start Google Play! Ignore any crashes in sign in
   process.
5. Flash benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip and restart the
   virtual device. Open Google Play in virtual device,update all
   installed applications.
6. Start Google Now with long touch on home button to force dialog with
   request to update Google Play Services. Update Google Play Services.
   Now the device is prepared with working Google Play and Google Play
   Services.

[Genymotion android 6.0 with Google play service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuaCg.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help